# Change or delete default PHP version (5.2 to 5.4) Debian Squeeze

Tags: php, apache, debian

so I have problem dealing with changing the default PHP version used. 
The environment is Debian Squeeze with PHP 5.2.17 installed. I've added dotdeb repository with PHP 5.4 for Debian Squeeze and installed everything. I was expecting that it'll do the upgrade from 5.2 to 5.4 but now I have two PHP versions installed.

```
    php -v gives 5.2.17

    phpinfo(); gives 5.2.17

    php5 -v gives 5.4.45
```

My question is how to delete PHP 5.2 or change default version used by httpd.
I've tried changing that in .htaccess file of subfolder but nothing really happens.
The server has weird configuration involving VirtualHosts and is started not by /etc/init.d/apache2 but /etc/init.d/httpd. I can't really change anything to that.

Comment: You need to update your OS. Extended support for Debian Squeeze ended in February 2016. This means you haven't been receiving security updates in over a year.

Comment: I've updated to Debian Wheezy, but the problem still persist.